# My windows 10 got deactivated and i want to change some taskbar settings

Tags: windows-10

My windows 10 got deactivated and i want to change some taskbar settings (hide labels on opened apps). Is there a way I can modify them?

Comment: Re-activate Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Click on Start, Settings, About, and at (near) the bottom of the right side, you should be able to re-activate Windows. (My Windows is activated so I cannot see the exact text).

When you activate, if there is an issue, there will be a contact phone number.

Call Microsoft Support and get them to activate.

I am sure you have a legitimate OEM license from the Computer Manufacturer.